# Как заставить работать z-index?

Tags: css, position, z-index

Не могу понять, хочу что бы первый блок при наведении (hover) перекрывал нижний блок, а он его сдвигает.  `position: relative;` и `z-index` проставил но без успеха! Что я делаю не так?

```css
.cardhe{
background:#000;    
width: 200px;
margin: auto;   
color: white;}

.pricepu:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
    z-index: 2;
 
}
.pricepu {

    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    text-overflow: clip;
    display: block;
    margin: 1px 4px;
    min-height: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
.text {position: relative;
z-index: 1;
background: blueviolet;}
```

```html
 
  
<article class="cardhe">

 <div class="pricepu">111 111 222222 333333 55555 6543453 6453</div>
<div class="text"> zzzzzzzzzzz   
 </div>
 
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что position: relative не извлекает элемент из потока. По ховеру у Вас размер элемента увеличивается, соответственно, увеличивается и занимаемое им место в потоке. Потому и нижний элемент сдвигается. Z-index здесь не поможет.

Если Вы хотите просто наслоения одного элемента на другой, то надо использовать position: absolute. Правда, поскольку такое позиционирование извлекает элемент из потока, для него придётся искусственно освободить место, задав родителю нужный padding-top:

```css
.cardhe{
    background:#000;    
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;   
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.pricepu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    text-overflow: clip;
    display: block;
    margin: 1px 4px;
    min-height: 25px;
}
.pricepu:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
}
.text {
    background: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<article class="cardhe">

 <div class="pricepu">111 111 222222 333333 55555 6543453 6453</div>
<div class="text"> zzzzzzzzzzz</div>
 
</article>
```